# Where should I place the event listener?

Tags: java, swing

I made many of objects such as JButton, JLabel, JCheckBox, etc. And I've added an event listener to the object. Like this.
object obj = new obj();
obj.listneraddActionListener(){};
However, if listener uses other objects, that objects must be created before listener code.
I'm thinking about whether I should sort object definition in advance or pull all listeners to below.
What should I do for this?

Edit:: I'm sorry, I didn't post because the code was too big. the below is part of the code. I got error message from checkboxes(chkName, chkAddress, chkType, chkComment)

```
    JButton btnSearch = new JButton("");
    btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {             
            String str = "";
            ResultSet rsSid, rsNM = null;
            int count = 0;

            if (chkName.isSelected()) {str += "(SELECT " + tableName + "_SID FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + tableName + "_NM LIKE '%" + txtSearch.getText() + "%') UNION "; ++count;}
            if (chkAddress.isSelected()) {str += "(SELECT " + tableName + "_SID FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + "ADDR LIKE '%" + txtSearch.getText() +"%') UNION "; ++count;}
            if (chkType.isSelected()) {str += "(SELECT " + tableName + "_SID FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + "TYPE LIKE '%" + txtSearch.getText() +"%') UNION "; ++count;}
            if (chkComment.isSelected()) {str += "(SELECT " + tableName + "_SID FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + "COMMENT LIKE '%" + txtSearch.getText() +"%') UNION "; ++count;}
            if (count == 0) return;

            if (txtSearch.getText() != "")
                str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 7) + ';';
            else
                str = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;

            rsSid = jdbc.executeQuery(conn, str);
            try {
                behindList.clear();
                lstSRmodel.clear();
                TableSummary temp = new TableSummary();
                while(rsSid.next()) {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= rsSid.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); ++i) {
                        temp.TABLE_SID = rsSid.getInt(i);
                        rsNM = jdbc.executeQuery(conn, "SELECT " + tableName + "_NM FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + tableName + "_SID = " + temp.TABLE_SID + ";");
                        if (rsNM.next()) {
                            temp.TABLE_NM = rsNM.getString(1);
                            behindList.add(new TableSummary(temp.TABLE_SID, temp.TABLE_NM));
                            lstSRmodel.addElement(temp.TABLE_NM);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    JCheckBox chkAll = new JCheckBox("\uC804\uCCB4");

    chkAll.setBounds(14, 75, 131, 27);
    contentPane.add(chkAll);

    JCheckBox chkName = new JCheckBox("\uC774\uB984");
    chkName.setBounds(14, 106, 131, 27);
    contentPane.add(chkName);

    JCheckBox chkAddress = new JCheckBox("\uC704\uCE58");
    chkAddress.setBounds(14, 137, 131, 27);
    contentPane.add(chkAddress);

    JCheckBox chkType = new JCheckBox("\uD0C0\uC785");
    chkType.setBounds(14, 168, 131, 27);
    contentPane.add(chkType);

    JCheckBox chkComment = new JCheckBox("\uC138\uBD80\uC0AC\uD56D");
    chkComment.setBounds(14, 199, 131, 27);
    contentPane.add(chkComment);
```

Comment: *if listener uses other objects, that objects must be created before listener code*: no, that's incorrect.

Comment: but I got an error message like "cannot be resolved" and message said me to create the variable... what did I make a mistake?

Comment: Somewhere, in the code that you didn't post, and that we can thus not read. Edit your question. It should looks like: *How can I fix the following error? <complete and exact error> in the following code <code that causes the error, as text, properly formatted>*

Comment: I'm really sorry... I edited the post..

Comment: You have two solutions: declare the variables in the class (i.e. make theme fields instead of local variables), or declare and initialize them before the call to addActionListener().

Comment: Way better now!

Comment: Also, don't set the bounds of your components. Use layout managers instead. And isolate the database handling code in a separate class.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I am a bit picky, but I won't use checkbox for this. You should use radio button and the buttons should be added to a radio group. This is so that the selection of one option automatically deselects the other (unless  you want to launch several queries with a single button action). Also, this might not be the best way to implement what you need. Your event handler is WAAAAAY too busy.

Comment: Also, instantiations of `TableSummary` objects looks very suspicious. Too many new objects created in my opinion. Run your application through a profiler and see how the line `behindList.add(new TableSummary(temp.TABLE_SID, temp.TABLE_NM));` performs. I have a feeling is this could be a hot spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your `ActionListener` and your business code: your should not execute a long running query in an `ActionListener` because it would freeze your application by blocking the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).

I would preferably do the following when dealing with Swing (or other framework such as Java FX, SWT, ...):

- Create GUI component such as field, ...
- Configure or "init" the layout, that is add the component to their parent and so on
- Configure any event listener

That would be (replace "init" by "configure" if you prefer):

```
private JCheckBox checkBox;

MyClass() { // constructor
  this.init();
}

void init() {
  initComponents();
  initEventListeners();
}

void initComponents() {
  this.checkBox = new JCheckBox("..."); // or in the constructor if you want final field.

  // layout for the parent component 
  this.add(new JLabel("Label 1"));
  this.add(checkBox);
}

void initEventListeners() {
  this.checkBox.addActionListener(System.out::println);
}
```

Also, event you attach to a Swing component should be kept as simple as possible if they are lambda or anonymous classes: instead, create a private method and use its reference:

```
  btnSearch.addActionListener(this::searchActionListener);
```

And the method in which I use another thread (`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`) to execute long running work outside the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). Otherwise, the interface would be frozen. The business method is done outside, in another object (called `business` here).

The search button should be disabled, otherwise the user (in that case) could spam the button leading to unwanted issues on the database...

```
private void searchActionListener(ActionEvent event) {
    btnSearch.setEnabled(false);  // user should not be able to search while it's running

    // extract Swing data before running outside the EDT
    String query = txtSearch.getText()
    boolean useName = chkName.isSelected();
    boolean useAddress = chkAddress.isSelected();
    // ... and so on

    // do work OUTSIDE the EDT
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(() -> {
      Result result = business.find(query, useName, useAddress);
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        processResult(result); // do whatever is needed
        btnSearch.setEnabled(true);
      });
    });
  }
```

As you can see, if you created your Swing component (`chkName`, ...) before the event listener, you may not reference them in the method: **you should create them as field to the class rather than as variable**.

Otherwise, you're bound to create them before the event listener.

Also, while not discussed in the question, you should rewrite your query because your are injecting SQL:

```
"(SELECT " + tableName + "_SID FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + tableName + "_NM LIKE '%" + txtSearch.getText() + "%') UNION ";
```

The `'%" + txtSearch.getText() + "%'` should be replaced by `?` and you should use a PreparedStatement to pass parameter rather than injecting it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer solves many of problems my program has. It's been a really great help. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @Y X, you have to make use of design patterns to resolve these sort of issues. Event Listeners only resolve the problem on how to handle (fulfill) the events. Using abstractions, or other strategies, to resolve dependencies at the time the even takes place, is another problem altogether that should not be part of the listeners directly. In theory, you can create your own event source class that could encapsulate all these dependencies when the radio or checkbox selections take place.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you have read this, but I would start by reading The Java™ Tutorials on [Writing Event Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html). This tutorial helped me a great deal when I was learning how to properly handle GUI events. Because there are so many events to handle, Java provides the primary interface called `EventListener` which has no methods (it's what is known as a ***Marker Interface***). Each `JComponent` defines what kind of event it must handle. For example, `JButton` objects are concerned about different set of events than `JFrame` objects.

The best thing you can do is understand the basic premise of why this API is needed for. GUIs must be event-driven because there is no effective way to capture a user interaction right at the moment the action takes place. For example, a `JButton` object must listen, at least, to "click" events. This much should be obvious to you. But there are other events you probably didn't think about. For instance, mousing over the button to show a tool tip.

To your question,

> If listener uses other objects, that objects must be created before listener code...
>    What should I do for this?

There are a few ways to handle this. I am going to show you very simple cases that, hopefully, you can use to expand on. Suppose you have a panel with two buttons, OK and Cancel. Obviously, you know these two buttons will perform different functions when clicked. For this illustration, the job they will do is irrelevant. So, I am just going to print out some message when clicked. The code snippet below shows only the relevant pieces. To handle button clicks, you must add an `ActionListener` to each of the buttons.

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        String name = button.getName(); // Assuming you set "OK" and "Cancel" as the names
        if (name.equals("OK")
            System.out.println("I will comply with your command!");
        else
            System.out.println("You cancelled your request.");
    }
}
```

Then, you can add a listener to your buttons like this...

```
MyActionListener listener = new MyActionListener();
cancelBtn.addActionListener(listener);
okBtn.addActionListener(listener);
```

This solution should work fine, but it doesn't scale very well. If you were to add more buttons to your application, having a single listener like this is bad because your listener will become overworked. A slightly better solution is to provide each instance with its own listener. You can do this by taking advantage of ***Anonymous Classes***. Here's how:

```
cancelBtn.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("I will comply with your command!");
    }
});
okBtn.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("You cancelled your request.");
    }
});
```

Some people don't like anonymous classes very much because it affects the readability of your code. I happen to like the fact that each object's instance has its own personalized listener that does precisely the job that the object instance needs to do when the action takes place.

I think this approach should work for your case just fine. There are other ways as well, but I think you should start using this simple approach until you gain more knowledge on how to handle events. Let me know what you think.

Comment: This solution was proposed before the OP edited this post. There was no posted code when he first asked his question. I think this disclaimer is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was helpful!